# Unable to grab image from usb Webcam

Tags: usb, debian, webcam

I would like to take snapshots from an USB webcam attached to my Raspberry Pi:

First, I checked the device:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0ac8:332d Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. Vega USB 2.0 Camera
```

When I'm trying to grab an Image I'm receiving the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 640x480 test.jpeg
--- Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video0 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
--- Capturing frame...
Timed out waiting for frame!
No frames captured.
```

What can be the problem, I tested this method on Ubuntu with success. What can be the problem on Debian?

Using a USB Hub:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0ac8:332d Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. Vega USB 2.0 Camera
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 640x480 test.jpeg
--- Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video0 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
--- Capturing frame...
Timed out waiting for frame!
No frames captured.
```

[This is the webcam.](http://www.ebay.de/itm/221080969343?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649)

[image]

Comment: Plugged directly into the Pi- Not enough power is my guess. Try using a compatibly power USB hub then try it.

Comment: I just tried with an USB hub with the same success.

Comment: Are you sure the usb hub works? Can you plug a keyboard and wireless in there and does it work on the Pi? It might detect it in the Pi but if you try to do something with it, it can start going wierd

Comment: I plug in a wifi module and a phone to the hub, all the device are visible. also I tested the wifi and it's working(I check only the scan)

Comment: If I unplug the hub power source than the phone is not visible otherwise it is.

Comment: I have same problem. Exact same hardware although the webcam is in a completely different housing. This webcam works without any problem on Ubuntu. Not working on Raspberry Pi. Tried both on a powered hub and directly connected. Webcam seems to be recognized in dmesg and is registered by uvcvideo. Using v4l-conf seems to show 'no overlay' error message.

Comment: The issue is present here as well. Different housing, same camera. fswebcam behaves the same here, and motion often tells me: "[0] Thread 1 - Watchdog timeout, trying to do a graceful restart". I've tried both the latest Raspian and Arch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have not already done so, you should try updating your firmware and kernel, in case you are using the officially supported Debian distribution (aka Raspbian). Just follow the instruction you can find [here](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update). They just fixed many USB issues (the usb host driver still has a lot of issues left), so you would want to try that.

Also, you should check if the system reports any error through the `dmesg` command. There is a check-list you can follow to help pinpoint your problem: you can find it [here](http://elinux.org/Rpi_USB_check-list).

Answer (score 2):

I've also experienced this issue when using an off-brand USB webcam I got off amazon for $4. It's (probably) due to the camera not getting enough power from the USB to capture.

Try a lower resolution like `320` by `240`:

`fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 320x240 test.jpeg`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my webcam and solved it by replacing `fswebcam` with `motion` -- it can capture images periodically too. You just have to write `snapshot_interval` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but was able to capture images running this as root (or sudo):

uvccapture -t0

Comment: Could you try and elaborate on your answer? Where you came across this solution, etc.