# fswebcam /boot/cmdline.txt interaction

Tags: cmdline.txt, fswebcam

Occasionally `fswebcam -r 640x480 -S10 image.jpg` would produce an `Error selecting input 0 VIDIOC_S_INPUT: Device or resource busy` error on my RPi 3.

I googled around a bit. I got some hits suggesting adding `dwc_otg.fiq_fsm_mask=0x3` to the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file might fix that. It does, but it introduces new errors, 'Timed out waiting for frame!`or`VIDIOC_DQBUF: No such device`.

The new errors occur every time I run `fswebcam` so I removed `dwc_otg.fiq_fsm_mask=0x3` and now I'm back to the original occasional error. But I'd like to be error free if possible.

Anyone out there understand this stuff well enough to suggest a fix?

Comment: What Operating System are you running? If it's Raspbian, which version of it? When was the last time you updated your Operating System?

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions listed [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/unable-to-grab-image-from-usb-webcam)? If/when you do, could you please update your question so we know if any of these options worked? If they didn't, this will help us narrow the possibilities for an error.

Comment: Running Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 4.9.35-v7+, last update/dist-upgrade early March. Generic 640x480 webcam plugged directly into a Pi3, no hub, 5v 3A power supply. Does anyone have a link to what dwc_otg.fiq_fsm_mask=0x3 actually is/does?